# Python: Random without repetition, but in def

Tags: python, function, random

I don't know how in def I can randomize sentences without repetition.

```
def yellowJeden(x,m):
    if m <= 25:
        zd1 = "Juz na samym poczatku meczu "+ x.strip() + " dostal"
        zd2 = "Juz w " + str(m) + ". minucie meczu zawodnik druzyny "+ druzyna1 + " dostal zolta kartke. "+ x.strip() + " sfaulowal swojego przeciwnika."
        zd3 = x.strip() + " juz w poczatkowych minutach meczu otrzymal zolta kartke za nieczyste zagranie. Sfaulowal on zowodnika druzyny przeciwnej. "

        zolta1 = [zd1, zd2, zd3]
        zolta1Index = random.randint(0, len(zolta1)-1)
        print zolta1[zolta1Index]
        zolta1.remove(zolta1[zolta1Index])

def akcja():
    a = line.split(',')
    min = int(a[1])
    if a[2] == ' yellow1':
        yellow1 = a[3]
        yellowJeden(yellow1, min)
    elif a[2] == ' yellow2':
        yellow2 = a[3]
        yellowDwa(yellow2, min)

for line in fh:
    if line.startswith('1.'):
        akcja()
    elif line.startswith('2.'):
        akcja()
    elif line.startswith('3.'):
        akcja()
```

It's more complicated. I don't want to write every sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
>>> import random
>>> def ShuffleSentences():
...     sentences = [ "First sentence", "Second sentence", "Third sentence", "last sentence"]
...     random.shuffle(sentences)
...     for s in sentences:
...         print s
...
>>> ShuffleSentences()
Second sentence
last sentence
Third sentence
First sentence
>>> ShuffleSentences()
Second sentence
First sentence
Third sentence
last sentence
>>> ShuffleSentences()
Second sentence
Third sentence
First sentence
last sentence
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a collection of sentences (eg. a list).
Use [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html?highlight=random.shuffle#random.shuffle) to shuffle the collection.
That way you avoid duplicates.